# How to set UIImage to an icon in ttf fonts

Tags: swift

I was setting image like this below from xcassets

```swift
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Info")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

I have a font file which have a lot of icons, how to set the image to those icons in the ttf font file?

Answer (score 1):

If you got your icons from the below list, You can use the [SwiftIcons](https://github.com/ranesr/SwiftIcons)

`Dripicons
Emoji
FontAwesome
Icofont
Ionicons
Linearicons
Map-icons
Material icons
Open iconic
State face icons
Weather icons`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the font easily in a `UILabel`, as that is where fonts are intended to be used, rather than in a `UIImageView`.

To use the font, you need to drag the `.ttf` or `.otf` file your your project.

The next step is to let iOS know about the font by including it in the `info.plist` file. This is taken from the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app).

> After adding the font file to your project, you need to let iOS know
>   about the font. To do this, add the key "Fonts provided by
>   application" to Info.plist (the raw key name is UIAppFonts). Xcode
>   creates an array value for the key; add the name of the font file as
>   an item of the array. Be sure to include the file extension as part of
>   the name.

Next, you will need to set the font of the label to your custom font. This can be done easily in Inferface Builder.

To apply the font in source code, follow these steps:

Get a list of all font family names, so you know what it is identified as.

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
    let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}
```

You can then apply it to a label like this (where `label` is an instance of `UILabel`:

```
guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "yourFont-Light", size: UIFont.labelFontSize) else {
    fatalError("Failed to load custom font")
}
label.font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: customFont)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```